# How can I upload ODR(On Demand Resources) to Apple's AppStore?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have read all the document about ODR in Apple's developer site. The document shows how to generate ODR files and how to host it on my own web server. However, there is no information about how to host my ODR to AppStore.

Should I upload it to AppStore manually or it is done by XCode automatically when building/publishing?

If it is uploaded automatically, is it possible to do it manually? Because in my company managing AppStore account is another staff, not the developer.

Comment: You can only use your own server for testing. Apple's server is used when your app is released on the store. If you have tagged your resources then they are automatically delivered when you upload your app to App Store Connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, technically you can do either.**

The nature of those resource depend on your App capabilities and features, but technically and legally if that content isn't strictly prohibited yes you may.

You can manage those resources via App Store Connect or internally, by API. But initially Apple provides a seamless in-house process for that, you may check again if that fill your needs and specifics.

In a nutshell, the process would happen automatically unless you want it to do it manually or by API.

You have an awesome day!